# Easier way to read sqlite3 row into object?

Tags: python, sqlite

In Python, I'm reading rows from sqlite3 into an object that's a simple data structure.  At the moment of assignment, I have to assign the row to a series of variables.  Is there a way to do this in a simpler manner?

I've included some sample code below that hopefully illustrates my problem.

```
import sqlite3

class studentDef(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstName = 'x'
        self.lastName  = 'x'
        self.id        = 'x'
        self.address1  = 'x'
        self.address2  = 'x'
        self.city      = 'x'
        self.state     = 'x'
        self.zip       = 'x'
        self.status    = 0

def main():
    mystudent = studentDef()
    db        = sqlite3.connect('students.sqlite3')
    cursor    = db.cursor()
    selectTxt = "select * from students where status = 1"
    cursor.execute(selectTxt)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for index in range(0,len(rows)):
        mystudent.firstName, mystudent.lastName, mystudent.id, mystudent.address1, \
            mystudent.address2, mystudent.city, mystudent.state, mystudent.zip, \
            mystudent.status = row[index]
        processStudent(mystudent)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My current code is reading in 50+ columns and the assignment statement is getting a bit hairy!  As I'm still developing, I'm constantly messing with the assignment statement while adding, removing, or modifying columns.

Is there an easier way to do something like:

```
mystudent = row[index]
```

My other problem is that I'm doing this in about 5 other programs.  So every time I change the database layout, I'm spending a lot of time updating all of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you've written the class initializer. A class should be responsible for setting its own data; there's no point writing an init function that sets the attributes to holding values and then relying on a process outside the class to set them to the actual values. So:

```
class studentDef(object):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, id, address1, address2, city, state, zip, status):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName  = lastName
        self.id        = id
        self.address1  = address1
        self.address2  = address2
        self.city      = city
        self.state     = state
        self.zip       = zip
        self.status    = status
```

Now you can just pass in the row, using the `*` syntax to expand the list into separate parameters:

```
cursor.execute(selectTxt)
for row in cursor:
   mystudent = studentDef(*row)
```

(note, in Python you should pretty much *never* iterate over `range(len(something))`, always iterate over the thing itself.)

It also sounds like `processStudent` should be a method of the studentDef class. Finally, note that Python style is to use InitialCaps for classes, and lower_case_with_underscore for attributes: StudentDef, first_name, last_name.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect!  Thanks so much!  I guess my FORTRAN77 is showing!  I never thought to re-instantiate the object every time through.  Thanks for the other tips, as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object-relational mapping (ORM) tool. Such a tool will map your SQLite3 database to Python objects (and vice-versa), reducing the amount of code.

Here is an example using [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/):

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('students.sqlite3')

class Student(Model):
    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    address1 = CharField()
    address2 = CharField()
    city = CharField()
    state = CharField()
    zip = CharField()
    status = SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

You can then query your students using:

```
>>> query = Student.select()
>>> [student.first_name for student in query]
['Charlie', 'Huey', 'Peewee']
>>> query[1]
<__main__.Student at 0x7f83e80f5550>
>>> query[1].first_name
'Huey'
```

There are others Python ORMs compatible with SQLite: [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) Models (for building web apps) and probably many others.